# I want to Implement this code with @SerializedName GSON object

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

> Want to implement @SerializedName Gson i dont know how to implement
>   Gson please help me how to implement @SerializedName GSON

```
public class ModelClass {

@SerializedName("longi")
public String longitudeServer;

@SerializedName("lati")
public String latitudeServer;

@SerializedName("uniqueid")
public String uniqueidSserver;

public ModelClass(){
    // blank constructor is required
}

public String getLongitude(){
    return longitudeServer;
}


public String getLatitude(){
    return latitudeServer;
}


public String getUniqueId(){
    return uniqueidSserver;
}


//... More setter and getter here
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:-problem is jumping current pointer.

creat method addMarker() in public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

```
private void addMarker() {
    try {
        //ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        //TODO: remove previus markers
        if (marker != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        for (LatLng object : latLngList)

            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));

        System.out.println(marker.getPosition() + "  Marker position.......");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // mMap.clear();
    }
}
```

and call it in

```
 if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (initMap()) {
            //  gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG, 15);

            mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mLocationClient.connect();


            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        addMarker();

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

In OnPostExecute

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // dialog.cancel();
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receicve data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (result == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
//            try {
//                //ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
//                //TODO: remove previus markers
//                if (marker != null) {
//                    mMap.clear();
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//
//                }
//                for (LatLng object : latLngList)
//
//                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));
//
//                System.out.println(marker.getPosition() + "  Marker position.......");
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                // mMap.clear();
//            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108544/discussion-on-answer-by-nguyn-trung-hiu-i-want-to-implement-this-code-with-se).

Answer (score 2):

Dummy use of SerializedName

```
    @SerializedName("Savings")
    private String savings;
```

You will need to add

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

inside dependencies in build.gradle

Comment: where it use?
@SerializedName("Savings")
    private String savings;

Comment: received error in this line                         ModelClass s = LoganSquare.parse(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ModelClass.class);

Comment: public class ModelClass {

    @SerializedName("longi")
    public String longitudeServer;

    @SerializedName("lati")
    public String latitudeServer;

    @SerializedName("uniqueid")
    public String uniqueidSserver;

    public ModelClass(){
        // blank constructor is required
    }

    public String getLongitude(){
        return longitudeServer;
    }

    
    public String getLatitude(){
        return latitudeServer;
    }

   
    public String getUniqueId(){
        return uniqueidSserver;
    }


    //... More setter and getter here
}

Comment: How i implement in DoInBacground?

Comment: When you get response you can parse it using `ModelClass modelClass = new Gson().fromJson(response,
                        ModelClass.class);`

This will parse the response and fill the data in your modelClass object.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonElement
                                                                               at com.example.muhammad.try1.MainActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:300)

Comment: on this line 
                        ModelClass modelClass = new Gson().fromJson((JsonElement) response, ModelClass.class);

Comment: because this line ModelClass modelClass = new Gson().fromJson(response, ModelClass.class);
shows error cannor resolved method